# How to overclock Snapdragon 200 processor in Huawei Ascend Y530?

Tags: overclocking

Can Snapdragon 200 processor be overclocked? I have Huawei Ascend Y530, and I want to overclock this processor? How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried with any of the [CPU Settings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_539) apps?

Comment: @Izzy give me name of some apps

Comment: Have you followed the link? Names there, including links (even to reviews, when available).

Comment: Anytime! I'm just updating the list currently (adding a few more candidates) – so when still in need, check back with it in half an hour or so :) When you've been successful with any of them, please come back here and [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) to help others :) Good luck!

Comment: And if you do succeed in overclocking this processor, then do come back to post an answer so that others may benefit from it. :)